# An "undefined" showed when printing items of an array

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, undefined

I created a Javascript code to show a list of items as below, but there's an unexpected `undefined` showed before the ordered list. I have no idea how it showed there.

Is there any variable not defined or wrongly inserted in this block of code?

[Demo is also on JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qajawacelu/edit?js,output). (And [here](http://jsbin.com/januvujefa/edit?js,output) is another better way to write the code with the same goal.)

```js
var playList = [
  "First Life",
  "Spaceman",
  "Run run run"
];

function print(message) {
  message += "<ol>";
  for (var i=0; i<playList.length; i+=1) {
    message += "<li>" + playList[i]+"</li>";
  }
  message += "</ol>";
  document.write(message);
}

print();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're not passing anything to the `print()` as parameter, `message` is by default `undefined`.

You can use OR `||` to set the value of `message` to empty string when it is not passed to the function.

```js
var playList = [
  "First Life",
  "Spaceman",
  "Run run run"
];

function print(message) {
  message = message || ''; // If no message is passed, use empty string

  message += "<ol>"; // Removed + from here

  for (var i = 0; i < playList.length; i += 1) {
    message += "<li>" + playList[i] + "</li>";
  }
  message += "</ol>";
  document.write(message);
}

print();
```

You can also shorten your code as follow:

```js
var playList = [
  "First Life",
  "Spaceman",
  "Run run run"
];

function print(message) {
  document.write((message || '') + '<ol><li>' + playList.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ol>');
}

print();
```

```css
ol {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Even if `message` is a parameter in the function `print`, I still have to define it?

Comment: @chenghuayang You can use `message = message || '';`, I've updated answer, kindly check it

Comment: I don't quite understand this `message = message || ''`. Does this mean that we should specify `message` to itself or just nothing? And, we have to do this because the next line, `message += "<ol>"`, needs to pass something in it?

Comment: @chenghuayang `message = message || ''` means, if the `message` is not passed to function `print()` like in the above case, `message` will be initialized to `''` empty string, else `message` will be the passed value. This will prevent you from showing `undefined`

Comment: @chenghuayang Because, you didn't pass any parameter to the `print()` function when you're expecting it

Comment: Oh I got it. Sorry for that. We still need an empty string to add something after it.

Comment: Can you explain more about this, *else message will be the passed value*? So far I know why to add empty string, but have no idea about this. (You can edit in your answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88462/discussion-between-tushar-and-chenghuayang).